# How calculate a value based on the sum of rows to get a value

Tags: c#, sql

I have a C# application that is use for exporting data from a SQL data base. It pulls data from a view and exports it to Excel for importing to our payroll system. I need to calculate the overtime amount. I have the following code but it does not calculate the the amount of overtime. I have searched the internet for a solution but have not had any luck.[image: this is the out put I get]

```
SELECT  [Co Code]
    , [Empl No]
    , [Task CD]
    , [Day No]
    , [Fund Co Code]
    , [Job No]
    , [Equip Cost Cde]
    , SUM([Reg Hrs Jc]) AS [Reg Hrs Jc]
    ,(CASE WHEN [Reg Hrs Jc] > 40 THEN [Reg Hrs Jc] - 40 ELSE 0 END) AS [Ot Hrs Jc]
FROM         dbo.MIS_FTTIMECARD_OT
WHERE     ([Date Worked] BETWEEN '8/11/2013' AND '8/17/2013')
GROUP BY [Co Code]
    , [Empl No]
    , [Task CD]
    , [Day No]
    , [Fund Co Code]
    , [Job No]
    , [Equip Cost Cde]
    , (CASE WHEN [Reg Hrs Jc] > 40 THEN [Reg Hrs Jc] - 40 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: You don't give enough info.  explain your data more, does each employee have one row per week or day.  are you trying to get the total hours per employee? etc. just list the table definition and give some good sample data.  Also, if you didn't have the spaces in your column names, you wouldn't need the annoying [braces] all over the place.

Comment: It appears that you are basing your overtime criteria on the value of field Reg Hrs Jc instead of the sum of the values.  Also, this sort of thing, sum(fieldname) as fieldname tends to cause problems.  I suggest using a different alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should work with a subquery, that will allow you to first sum up the amount of time worked:

```
SELECT t.*, (CASE WHEN [Reg Hrs Jc] > 40 THEN [Reg Hrs Jc] - 40 ELSE 0 END) AS [Ot Hrs Jc]
FROM 
   (SELECT [Co Code], [Empl No], [Task CD], [Day No], [Fund Co Code], [Job No], [Equip Cost Cde], SUM([Reg Hrs Jc]) AS [Reg Hrs Jc] FROM dbo.MIS_FTTIMECARD_OT
   WHERE ([Date Worked] BETWEEN '8/11/2013' AND '8/17/2013')
   GROUP BY [Co Code], [Empl No], [Task CD], [Day No], [Fund Co Code], [Job No], [Equip Cost Cde]) AS t
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you very much. I had tried to use a sub query but did not have it format correctly I guess. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To extend other's answers, your naming convention is probably what has led to confusion.

Consider the following snippet of your code:

```
, SUM([Reg Hrs Jc]) AS [Reg Hrs Jc]
,(CASE WHEN [Reg Hrs Jc] > 40 THEN [Reg Hrs Jc] - 40 ELSE 0 END) AS [Ot Hrs Jc]
```

By renaming, it becomes clear what's happening:

```
, SUM([Reg Hrs Jc]) AS [Reg Hrs Jc Sum]
,(CASE WHEN [Reg Hrs Jc] > 40 THEN [Reg Hrs Jc] - 40 ELSE 0 END) AS [Ot Hrs Jc]
```

I think you have effectively tried to do the following, which would not work had it not shared an actual column name

```
, SUM([Reg Hrs Jc]) AS [Reg Hrs Jc Sum]
,(CASE WHEN [Reg Hrs Jc Sum] > 40 THEN [Reg Hrs Jc Sum] - 40 ELSE 0 END) AS [Ot Hrs Jc]
```

You can't nickname a column and then reference it by that new title within the same scope, so you should base Ot Hrs Jc on SUM([Reg Hrs Jc]) as others have suggested.